# How to set selected value as empty for dropdownlist via jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery to populate dropdownlist, the codes are like below:

```
 var myOptions = {  
   val1 : 'text1',   
   val2 : 'text2',
   val3 : '' 
    };
 $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {  
   $('#mySelect').append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)    
);

 });
```

now I have populate 3 items in my dropdown, and now I want to set my dropdownlist selected value with '', just like:

```
$("#mySelect option contain('')").attr(selected,true).
```

Actually, this will get all 3 items so that it will not set '' as selected value, is there any way that i can do this?

Comment: If you never accept a correct answer, you don't reward those who attempt to help you out; therefore, hurting your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: You have to accept answers to your question. Just click the checkmark next to the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Do you really need to use `.html(text)` to set the label? If you don't do HTML inside the text, you should use `.text(text)` to prevent XSS vulnerabilities. This is exceedingly important if `text` may contain user input.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$("#mySelect option[value='']").attr('selected', true)
```

Comment: @JoshPinter can you do `.val(null)`

Answer (score 12):

It will do the same .
`$('#elemtId').val('')`
Will achieve same result

Comment: This tends to fail in some cases. In my particular case in mobile Chrome for iOS it doesn't work properly if it's inside a change event.

Comment: for multiselect this will bind an empty string

Answer (score 2):

What I am getting from your question is that you want to set the selected value as empty.
If so, you can try
  `$(“#elementId”).val('');`
e.g.
   `$(“#val3”).val('');`

otherwise if you want to set any specific value as selected by finding the option by its text, try [this](https://bugs.code.blog/2019/04/05/find-a-value-of-dropdown-by-text-and-set-it-as-selected-value-in-jquery/).

The last thing you might want to do as you mentioned above is that you want to set val3 as selected, i.e. setting a specific known option as selected, try [this](https://bugs.code.blog/2019/03/31/setting-selected-value-of-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery/)
I have tried all these ways...Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regrettable it's very improvable as it relies 100% on external links. It would be great if you could integrate the essential parts of the linked solutions directly here in your answer. In the current state your contribution is likely being deleted. Here you might find some useful tips [how to improve your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!